# Responsive Image Grid with hover effects

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am currently trying to edit the code attached in :

https://jsfiddle.net/nxyh1zkg/3/

Currently it is set to have 2 columns and then using media queries goes to 1 column when under 50em. I am trying to instead have 3 columns 2 rows, then to 2 columns 3 rows, then 1 column 6 rows. But everytime I edit the code I mess something up with the margins. Been working on it for a day now and everything I do either screws up the hover effects or the margins are way off, so its time to ask for help haha. So any advice would be appreciated .

To make the 3 images fit and be at a decent size I do not mind decreasing the paddings on the left and right side to where its almost full width for the image grid. I actually prefer that.

HTML

```
                <div class="grid">
                <figure class="effect-apollo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/18.jpg" alt="img18"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
                        <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
                <figure class="effect-apollo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
                        <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
      <figure class="effect-apollo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
                        <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="grid">
                <figure class="effect-apollo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/18.jpg" alt="img18"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
                        <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
                <figure class="effect-apollo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
                        <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
      <figure class="effect-apollo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
                        <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the `.grid figure` a `width: 31%` so you can get 3 columns and remove `min-width`

```
.grid figure {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 1%;
    max-width: 480px;
    max-height: 360px;
    width: 31%; /* add this */
    height: auto;
    background: #3085a3;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and add this so you can get 2 columns

```
@media screen and (max-width: 70em){
  .grid figure {
        width: 48%;
    }
}
```

Check out the working demo:

```css
*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { display: table; content: ''; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

body {
 background: #2f3238;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
 outline: none;
 color: #3498db;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
 color: #528cb3;
}

section {
 padding: 1em;
 text-align: center;
}

.content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1000px;
}

.content > h2 {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 4em 1% 0;
 color: #484B54;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.content > h2:first-child {
 padding-top: 0em;
}

/* Header */
.codrops-header {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 4em 1em;
 text-align: center;
}

.codrops-header h1 {
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 4em;
 line-height: 1.3;
}

.codrops-header h1 span {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
 color: #74777b;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 45%;
}

/* Demo links */
.codrops-demos {
 clear: both;
 padding: 1em 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.content + .codrops-demos {
 padding-top: 5em;
}

.codrops-demos a {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 5px;
 padding: 1em 1.5em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.codrops-demos a:hover,
.codrops-demos a:focus,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo {
 background: #3c414a;
 color: #fff;
}

/* To Navigation Style */
.codrops-top {
 width: 100%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 0.69em;
 line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
 float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
 margin: 0 4px;
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 line-height: 1;
 speak: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon-drop:before {
 content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon-prev:before {
 content: "\e004";
}

/* Related demos */
.related {
 clear: both;
 padding: 6em 1em;
 font-size: 120%;
}

.related > a {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px 10px;
 padding: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #4f7f90;
 text-align: center;
}

.related a:hover {
 border-color: #39545e;
}

.related a img {
 max-width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.related a:hover img,
.related a:active img {
 opacity: 1;
}

.related a h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.5em 0 0.3em;
 max-width: 300px;
 text-align: left;
}

/* Demo ad design */
body #cdawrap {
 background: none;
 top: 50px;
 border: none;
}

body #cdawrap a {
 color: #fff !important;
}

body #cda-remove {
 color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
 .codrops-header {
  font-size: 75%;
 }
 .codrops-icon span {
  display: none;
 }
}
.grid {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em 0 4em;
 max-width: 1000px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Common style */
.grid figure {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 10px 1%;
 max-width: 480px;
 max-height: 360px;
 width: 31%;
 height: auto;
 background: #3085a3;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure img {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 min-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.grid figure figcaption {
 padding: 2em;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grid figure figcaption::before,
.grid figure figcaption::after {
 pointer-events: none;
}

.grid figure figcaption,
.grid figure figcaption > a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */
/* For some effects it will show as a button */
.grid figure figcaption > a {
 z-index: 1000;
 text-indent: 200%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}

.grid figure h2 {
 word-spacing: -0.15em;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.grid figure h2 span {
 font-weight: 800;
}

.grid figure h2,
.grid figure p {
 margin: 0;
}

.grid figure p {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size: 68.5%;
}

/* Individual effects */

/*-----------------*/
/***** Apollo *****/
/*-----------------*/

figure.effect-apollo {
 background: #3498db;
}

figure.effect-apollo img {
 opacity: 0.95;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05,1.05,1);
 transform: scale3d(1.05,1.05,1);
}

figure.effect-apollo figcaption::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
 transition: transform 0.6s;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.9,1.4,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) translate3d(0,-100%,0);
 transform: scale3d(1.9,1.4,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

figure.effect-apollo p {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 3em;
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 150px;
 border-right: 4px solid #fff;
 text-align: right;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
 transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-apollo h2 {
 text-align: left;
}

figure.effect-apollo:hover img {
 opacity: 0.6;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

figure.effect-apollo:hover figcaption::before {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.9,1.4,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: scale3d(1.9,1.4,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

figure.effect-apollo:hover p {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}



/* Media queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 70em){
  .grid figure {
  width: 48%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
 .content {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .grid figure {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <figure class="effect-apollo">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/18.jpg" alt="img18" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
      <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect-apollo">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
      <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect-apollo">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
      <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <figure class="effect-apollo">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/18.jpg" alt="img18" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
      <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect-apollo">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
      <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="effect-apollo">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="img22" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Strong <span>Apollo</span></h2>
      <p>Apollo's last game of pool was so strange.</p>
      <a href="#">View more</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey John. Thanks for the response but it does not go from 3x2 to 2x3 which keeps everything even and no single line images like its doing now. Any idea how to transition the way I indicated or is that not going to be possible?